# lightning-combobox Will not display dynamically retrieved options

Tags: lightning-web-components

I cannot get lightning-combobox to display dynamically retrieved options from Apex. It is rarely needed so I wrote a getter using an imperative call to get the data. I also tried the below as a static function. Neither work.

The js function. The Apex is working as intended and returning data.

```
get availableLifepaths() {
    let lifepaths = [];
    
    GetLifePaths({
        recipientAccountId : this.activeAcctId
    })
    .then(result => {           
        for(let lifepath of result) {
            if(lifepath.status == 'Active') continue;
            lifepaths.push({label: lifepath.name, value: lifepath.mtmId});
        }
        //There is data here and it looks fine. 
        return lifepaths;
    }) 
    .catch(error => {
       //No error is thrown
    })

    //This works for some reason. I tried with values the apex returned also, still worked.
    // return [
    //     { label: 'WI', value: 'WI' },
    //     { label: 'WY', value: 'WY' }
    // ];
}
```

The combobox:

```
<lightning-combobox
 class="normalText"
 name="Lifepath"
 label="Life Path"
 value={availableLifepaths}
 options={availableLifepaths}
 onchange={handleFieldChange} >
</lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: I've changed to a callback model, which is how I do all my option requests. Make sure the data is coming back to you in a format that is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use a getter in this situation - the getter calls, but runs to the end and returns nothing - because you are calling an async function.

I normally initiate by setting up in the connected callback like this:

**EDIT**

Here is how I actually do it:

```
@track let availableLifepaths = [];

connectedCallback(){
    //calling the invoke function defined below
    invokeGetLifepaths(this.activeAcctId, (data) => {
      let temp = [];
      console.log(data);
      for(let lifepath of result) {
        if(lifepath.status == 'Active') continue;
        temp.push({label: lifepath.name, value: lifepath.mtmId});
      }
      this.availableLifepaths = temp;
    });
}

//actual function definition
invokeGetLifepaths = (acctId, callback) => {
  getLifePaths({recipientAccountId : acctId})
    .then((result) => {
      callback(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

To illustrate more clearly, the order of execution for your original code is:

- getter called
- async function called
- getter returns (nothing)
- async function returns
- callback function returns - but simply passes `lifepaths` back to the calling function - it has nowhere to go, as the calling function has already returned it's value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the order of operations. Unfortunately, calling it the standard way doesn't work either

Comment: can you put your standard way code up? I wonder if the problem is your `this` definition - see I used an arrow function to eliminate any issues with what your `this` is.

Comment: To the person who downvoted... any particular reason why? You may not have noticed that the code is correct - block one is the call+callback, block two is the function definition - I have renamed and reformatted to make this more clear.

Comment: Hey thanks Caspar. I ended up getting it in a large part thanks to this. The issue seems to be that the combobox only gets picklist values once, and if the code hasn't completed by then you're SOL. I moved it up in the order of operations and it worked. I really appreciate the help!